# set-acl giving UnauthorizedAccessException: Attempted to perform an unauthorized operation

Tags: powershell, permissions

I got short powershell script to add one user to permissions on a few folders under c:\windows\winsxs using set-acl. ($ffn changes)

```
$ffn="c:\windows\winsxs\wow64_microsoft-windows-wpd-busenumservice_31bf3856ad364e35_6.1.7600.16385_none_de47cc4f1a142cbc"
$Acl = Get-Acl $ffn; 
$Ar = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule ("hastieuk\administratoruk","FullControl", "Allow")   ;
$Acl.SetAccessRule($Ar)  ;       
Set-Acl $ffn $Acl   ;
```

It works fine on some of them but on the rest it gives "UnauthorizedAccessException: Attempted to perform an unauthorized operation." error message. But if I try to do it manually it works fine. I am running Powershell as elevated user.
Thanks